# Why is this scala code not inferring type?

Tags: scala

I am building a aggregation framework with some code which looks like this

```
trait Aggregate[T <: Aggregate[T, K], K] { self: T =>
  def plus(another: T): T

  def show: K
}
```

I have couple of aggregations like this,

```
case class Count(value: Long = 1) extends Aggregate[Count, Long] {
  def plus(another: Count) = Count(value + another.value)

  def show = value
}
```

Once i define a aggregation which is like this,

```
case class By[T <: Aggregate[T, K], K, G](values: HashMap[G, T]) extends Aggregate[By[T, K, G], Map[G, K]] {
  override def plus(another: By[T, K, G]): By[T, K, G] = By(values.merged(another.values){case ((k1,v1), (k2,v2)) => (k1, v1 plus v2)})

  override def show: Map[G, K] = values.map{case (k,v) => k -> v.show}
}

object By {
  def apply[T <: Aggregate[T,K], K, G](key:G, value:T):By[T, K, G] = By(HashMap(key -> value))
}
```

I cannot write something like this

```
By("key1", Count(100))
```

Instead i had to write this

```
By[Count, Long, String]("key1", Count(100))
```

Since its not figuring out the `Long` part, I hate to specify those types, is there a cleaner way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trick I learned:

```
object By {
  def apply[T <: Aggregate[T,K], K, G](key:G, value:T with Aggregate[T,K]):By[T, K, G] = By(HashMap(key -> value))
}
```

The `with Aggregate[T,K]` refinement somehow helps the compiler figure out the types.

Comment: value is technically a [compound type](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/compound-types).

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't need it, since i said `T` extend `Aggregate[T,K]`. May be some technical limitation in the unification algorithm which i am not able to see.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [`Monoid`](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Monoid.html) and [`Show`](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Show.html) type classes. You may even want to use kittens (sorry, don't have enough rep to add another link; just Google "scala kittens derivation") to automatically derive the `Monoid` and `Show` instances for your case classes.

Comment: If you're not familiar with this pattern here is a worked example  http://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html

Comment: Thanks Paul, The primary problem that i am facing right now is i want to serialize these semigroups into a key value store and i wont know what semigroup instance it is at compile time. So wanted the semigroup itself to be polymorphic and have the binary operation, (I might have to persist the typeclass Semigroup along with it otherwise).